# Iterating Through PHP Array for Chart Display

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having trouble iterating through a PHP array in order to display a chart. Right now, my code is only resulting in the display of one column in the chart (this column is displaying correctly), but I can't seem to get other columns to display.

This is my code right now (in a php section at the top of my html page). I know that the issue is with this section of code, because the chart is rendering perfectly, but just not adding a column for each record in the table.

I'd really appreciate any insight into the mistakes I'm making here. Thank you.

```
$valueAnimalType = $_POST['animaltype'];

$connect = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","____","_____",3306);
$result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM DISPOSAL");
$datas = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $datas[] = $row;
    }

    foreach ($datas as $data){
        $datas = array(
        array('y' => $data[$valueAnimalType], "label" => $data['DisposalName'] ));
    }
}
```

Comment: What format are you expecting the result to be? Maybe provide a sample expected result?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1):

modify your code here:

```
    foreach ($datas as $data) {

        //LINE BELOW    
        $datas [] =
            array('y' => $data[$valueAnimalType], "label" => $data['DisposalName']);
        //LINE ABOVE
    }
```

you're overwriting your $datas each time loop passes with last record, now it's appending new item to array